# why is my char array printing in lower case after i've converted it to uppercase?

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

I'm trying to do the [CS50 substitution problem](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/2/substitution/). My code uses [cs50.h library](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/) to handle strings.

Currently I have a function to convert a string to lower case, and one to convert it to uppercase:

```
string strtolower(string text)
{
    int length = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        text[i] = tolower(text[i]);
    }
    return text;
}

string strtoupper(string text)
{
    int length = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        text[i] = toupper(text[i]);
    }
    return text;
}
```

I have checked and they are returning the correct uppercase and lowercase string.

However when I call them in main as:

```
string key_upper = strtoupper(key);
string key_lower = strtolower(key);
printf("%s\n", key_upper);
printf("%s\n", key_lower);
```

I get (using `key` `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` or `ffffffffffffffffffffffffff`, same result):

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

if I print like this:

```
string key_upper = strtoupper(key);
string key_lower = strtolower(key);
printf("%s\n", key_upper);
printf("%s\n", key_lower);
printf("%s\n", strtoupper(key));
```

then I get:

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffff
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

if I do:

```
printf("%s\n", key_upper);
printf("%s\n", key_lower);
printf("%s\n", strtoupper(key));
printf("%s\n", key_lower);
printf("%s\n", strtolower(key));
```

then I get:

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffff
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
ffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Does anyone know what is happening? Why so I get different results depending on whether I print the return of the function directly vs storing it in a variable first? Is it just some funk related to how cs50.h implements strings? **How could I store the return in a variable successfully and call it later?**

My full code: https://pastebin.com/pvUzT6iv

Tried:

```
printf("%s\n", key_upper);
printf("%s\n", key_lower);
```

Expected:

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
ffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Got:

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: Your functions `strtolower` and `strtoupper` modify the string in-place (and return a pointer to the same string).  So `key_upper` and `key_lower` actually point to the same string (upper or lower depending on which function was called last - in your case it is `strtolower`).

Comment: You are using the same memory space for the string. The lines `text[i] = tolower(text[i]);` and `text[i] = toupper(text[i]);` replaces the existing characters; so, your last call dominates the output. You need to allocate a new memory space in the functions in order to get different output.

Comment: Either change `strtolower` and `strtoupper` to allocate and return a new string (but then the caller must remember to deallocate), or accept another parameter to be filled with the output (then the caller should both allocate and deallocate).

Comment: And you need to move `return true;` outside the `for` loop in `is_alphabetical()`, otherwise it always return on the first iteration.

Comment: @DavidRanieri thank you! hadn't gotten to debug that part yet, was stuck on this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the kind of misconception CS50 teaches. `string` is actually a `char*`, declared as `typedef char* string` which is incredibly bad practice.

So `string strtolower(string text)` is actually `char* strtolower(char* text)`. And since you modify the passed string `key`, that one changes in each function call. `key_upper` is *not* a copy of it, just a pointer pointing at the same space as `key`.

The quick fix is something like this:

```
string key_upper = strdup(key);
string key_lower = strdup(key);
key_upper = strtoupper(key_upper);
key_lower = strtolower(key_lower);
```

The longterm solution is to drop out of CS50 and find better study material that actually teaches how string handling and pointers work in C.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it clearly taking into consideration my current knowledge being fully based on cs50 classes. I guess I'm going to read the Kernighan book on C before I continue trying to solve problem sets.

Comment: You might want to pick up a modern one along with it. Something like *"Robert Seacord's Effective C".* Or *"Modern C"*.

Comment: @Haris thank you for the suggestions, I will look for these two.

Comment: @56492583 Modern C is available for free as pdf. https://hal.inria.fr/hal-02383654/document It isn't the most beginner-friendly C book, but _far_ better than K&R. Jens Gustedt is a recognized C expert and member of the current C committee, so the book is very much up to date.

Answer (score 1):

*Q. why is my char array printing in lower case after i've converted it to uppercase?*

Because this:

```
string key_upper = strtoupper(key);
```

converts all the characters (that weren't already and were lowercase alphabets) to uppercase.

`string key_upper` is pointing to a `char *` returned by the `strtoupper` function.

You then go on to declare another `char *` (under the hood, `string` is a `char *`) and initialising it with the pointer returned by the `strtolower` function.

Note that you passed the same `char *` to both the functions, and `upper_key` and `lower_key` are pointing at the same address. So if you change the memory contents of the address they were pointing to, the pointers would still be pointing to the same memory address. So this:

```
string key_lower = strtolower(key);
```

converts the characters back to lowercase.

```
+--------+              +--------+
+        +              +        +
+  ptr1  + ---> A <---  +  ptr2  + 
+        +              +        +
+--------+              +--------+
```

```
+--------+              +--------+
+        +              +        +
+  ptr1  + ---> a <---  +  ptr2  + 
+        +              +        +
+--------+              +--------+
```

See how they're still pointing to the same location? So now if you go on to print their contents, you'd get the same result. In this case, you called `strtoupper` first, so the output was all lowercase characters.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I definitely need to go study up on C beyond what this course offers.